# No turn off button ater update to 22.04

Tags: updates, 22.04, shutdown

We used to turn of the computer by clicking on a little x icon after clicking in the start menue, then a dialog would open turn of OK or cancel. But after Ubuntu 22.04 is installed, there is no x button anymor when clicking on start menue. Only way seems to be Control Alt Delete. Is there a way to have a icon one can click weith the mouse. If you know a way, I would be thankful, but please keep in mind Not every Ubuntu user is a software expoert who knows how to open and operate Terminals... So could you give exact instructions what to type in where. Many thanks

Comment: The switch icon in the very top right of your screen will bring up the power/log off/restart dialog popup you are familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

The poweroff button is accessed by clicking the ⏻ icon in the top right corner of the desktop.

1. Click the ⏻ icon to show a dropdown menu.
2. From the dropdown menu select *Power Off / Log Out* to show the Power Off / Log Out menu.
3. Select *Power Off*.
4. A small dialog window will open off which says: Power Off The system will power off automatically power off in 60 seconds. Click the  <kbd>Power Off</kbd>   button to shut down Ubuntu and power off the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean to shutdown your system. In Ubuntu 22.04 this would be done like this:

[image]

After that a dialog will open offering you the choice to cancel or to shutdown your system.

[image]